# update zip codes through backend

Tags: payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

we are using a module that allow me to restrict only some  zip codes for default "cash on delivery" payment method.

module **observer.php**

```
<?php
class Mfp_Cod_Model_Observer {

    public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');

        if($isModuleEnable) {

            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' ){

                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $add = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode = $add->getData('postcode');

                $comparisonMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/mode');
                $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');
                $isExist = false;

                if(trim($zipCodes) == '') {             
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                } else {    

                    if(strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) !==  false) {
                        $isExist = true;
                    }


                    if($isExist != true) {

                        $zipCodesArray = explode(',', nl2br($zipCodes));
                        if(count($elementLineArray) > 1) {
                            foreach($zipCodesArray as $codzipLine) {
                                $elementLineArray = explode('-', $codzipLine);
                                if(count($elementLineArray) == 2 && ( $postcode >= $elementLineArray[0] && $postcode <= $elementLineArray[1] )) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                } else if($postcode == $codzipLine) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $returnValue = '';
                        $returnValue = ($isExist)?true:false;

                    $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;

                }   

            } 
        }   
    }
}
```

we are using custom COD payment method, what changes we need to done so that it should work for custom COD.

custom paymentmethod.php

```
app/code/local/Exam/Mpcashondelivery/Model/Paymentmethod.php   

<?php

class Exam_Mpcashondelivery_Model_PaymentMethod extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

    /**
     * Payment Method features
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_code = 'mpcashondelivery';

    /**
     * Cash On Delivery payment block paths
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_formBlockType = 'mpcashondelivery/form';

    protected $_paymentMethod = 'mpcashondelivery';

    protected $_isGateway = false;
    protected $_canAuthorize = true;
    protected $_isInitializeNeeded      = true;
    protected $_canCapture = false;
    protected $_canCapturePartial = false;
    protected $_canRefund = false;
    protected $_canVoid = true;
    protected $_canUseInternal = true;
    protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping = true;


    public function initialize($paymentAction, $stateObject)    {
        $data = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
        if(isset($data['payment']['mpcod_captcha_code'])){
            $mpcod_captcha_code = $data['payment']['mpcod_captcha_code'];
            if(empty($_SESSION['captcha_code']) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['captcha_code'], $mpcod_captcha_code) != 0){
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('payment')->__('Invalid Captcha'));
            }else{
                return $msg=1;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check whether payment method can be used
     *
     * TODO: payment method instance is not supposed to know about quote
     *
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote|null $quote
     *
     * @return bool
     */

    public function isAvailable($quote = null)
    {


    if($quote){
        $restrictedZips = array(
        '110001'
        ,'560044'
        );


        $address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $customerZip = $address->getPostcode();
        if (!in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
            return false;
            }
        }   

        if($quote && $quote->getBaseGrandTotal()<Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/max_order_total') && $quote->getBaseGrandTotal()>Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/max_order_total')) {
            return false;
        }
        $specificcountry = explode(",",Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/specificcountry'));
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mpcashondelivery/allowspecific')!=0 ){
            if(!in_array($quote->getBillingAddress()->getCountry(),$specificcountry)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        $cod_charges = Mage::getModel('mpcashondelivery/pricerules')->getAppliedPriceRules();
        if($cod_charges['error']){            
            return false;
        }
        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

we uploaded these 3 pin codes in backend : 110001,110002,1234

when i tried : `var_dump($zipCodes); die();`  i got this result : `string(19) "110001,110002,1234,"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your custom shipping method code to the if statement like this:

```
if (
    $method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' || // the default shipping method method code
    $method->getCode() == 'mpcashondelivery'  // Or the custom CoD method code
   ) { ... }
```

Complete code of the `observer.php`:

```
<?php
class Mfp_Cod_Model_Observer {

    public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');

        if($isModuleEnable) {

            // CHANGES HERE
            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' || $method->getCode() == 'mpcashondelivery'){

                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $add = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode = $add->getData('postcode');

                $comparisonMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/mode');
                $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');
                $isExist = false;

                if(trim($zipCodes) == '') {             
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                } else {    

                    if(strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) !==  false) {
                        $isExist = true;
                    }


                    if($isExist != true) {

                        $zipCodesArray = explode(',', nl2br($zipCodes));
                        if(count($elementLineArray) > 1) {
                            foreach($zipCodesArray as $codzipLine) {
                                $elementLineArray = explode('-', $codzipLine);
                                if(count($elementLineArray) == 2 && ( $postcode >= $elementLineArray[0] && $postcode <= $elementLineArray[1] )) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                } else if($postcode == $codzipLine) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $returnValue = '';
                        $returnValue = ($isExist)?true:false;

                    $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;

                }   

            } 
        }   
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Try this:

```
<?php
class Mfp_Cod_Model_Observer {

    public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');

        if($isModuleEnable) {

            // CHANGES HERE
            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' || $method->getCode() == 'mpcashondelivery') {
                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $add = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode = $add->getData('postcode');
                $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');

                if(trim($zipCodes) == '' || strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) ===  false) {
                    $result->isAvailable = false; // CHANGES
                } else {
                    $result->isAvailable = true; // CHANGES
                }                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: now zip codes that we included in paymentmethod.php file , they are not allowing for COD, this is fine.

Comment: but zip codes that we saved in backend also not working. please help me to fix this.

Comment: @BabyinMagento What exactly doesn’t work?

Comment: i updated some zip codes in backend using [module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cashondelivery-based-on-zipcode.html) 

, only those zip codes should give an option to select "Custom COD" under payment method.

but for those zip codes, its not showing "custom COD" option under payment method.

Comment: what zip codes we enter in backend, atleast for those zip codes, it should show "custom cash on delivery" option under payment method.

Comment: @BabyinMagento What Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode') returns in the observer?

Comment: sorry ,i have no idea about that, how to check what it will returns in the observer ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento Please, add after $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode'); line var_dump($zipCodes); die(); refresh page and update your question with the result.

Comment: please check updated question inder "EDIT" section,  i got this result : `string(19) "110001,110002,1234,"`

Comment: @BabyinMagento I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: you are awesome devoloper,  what actually you done is just a miracle. now this gold [code]  is working for both norml cod & custom cod , unbelievable. Thanks a lot for your support....